# Regresssion of Accurate Data

Tags: regression, predictive-models, nonlinear-regression

I'm collecting calibration data for a device which involves three variables $S$, $L$, and $x$. For a given coordinate $(S, L)$, the device will provide me with the corresponding value of $x$ to a high level of accuracy (within 1%). I have used the device to collect values of $x$ for a range of points $(S, L)$.

Now, I'd like to write an equation which produces $S$ given the other two variables (and a similar equation for $L$). While the input values for my known variables may not be exactly a combination that I have tested, it will be within the tested range. For my application, the accuracy of the output is **paramount** - ideally, my regression equation will be nearly as accurate as the device.

I have an *approximate* model equation for the data, and I previously used a least squares fit to fit the model equation to the data I collected. While this provided a reasonable fit, the model equation isn't perfect due to real-world imperfections in the physical device, and the equation loses accuracy for certain values of the variables.

It seems "wasteful" in some sense to use an imperfect regression on perfect data points. Without knowing the exact form of the model equation, how can I regress this data in the most accurate way possible?

Comment: First you say you have perfectly accurate data. Then you say there are imperfections in the measuring device. I'm confused.

Comment: Is there a non-linearity issue here?  If your measurements are accurate but the device produces non-linear effects then linear regression will certainly make inaccurate predictions.

Comment: @PeterFlom In retrospect, my wording was pitiful. When I said "perfectly accurate data," I meant that the data points are exact values on the curve I seek rather than points which estimate the curve I seek.

Comment: @Henry I'm not using a linear regression. Rather, I set up an equation involving the three variables and several parameters, and used Numpy to find the values of the parameters which minimized the sum of the squares of the differences between both sides of the equation for each data point.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you have or what you want.

Comment: @PeterFlom I seek an equation which produces $S$ as a function of $x$ and $L$ (and another equation $L$ as a function of $x$ and $S$). I know that the data points I have are very close to the curve I seek (where "very close" means "within the accuracy required"). AFAIK, this differs from the standard regression problem that I've been exposed to: in a "standard" problem, the data points are scattered, and the predictive equation tries to *best* model the data, but here, the predictive equation should very accurately fit each individual data point. What method should I use to find this equation?

Comment: @PeterFlom To be honest, however, I'm not sure if this is different from a traditional regression problem.

Comment: Do you mean that you have very little data, but it is very accurate?

Comment: @PeterFlom No, I have a lot of data (moreover, I can always take additional data) *and* it's very accurate. I'm trying to get a curve which takes advantage of these two characteristics. I'm looking into interpolation right now to see if that resolves my issues.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, then S and L are known precisely, while x has a noise.
In this case I would fit a smooth surface, with something like a smoothing spline, where you can play with a roughness penalty setting. Then when you need to find S from L and x, I'd simply pick the point on this surface. The same surface is used to find L for given S and x.

Look at [spatial interpolation techniques](http://www.nuim.ie/staff/dpringle/courses/hdip/gis10.pdf) to see what I mean by fitting a surface.

Comment: If $S$ and $L$ are precisely known then this is a duplicate question asking about regression or response surfaces. The novelty here--if *I* understand correctly--is that $x$ is the value that is precisely known but $S$ and $L$ are uncertain.  This is a case of "inverse regression."

Comment: @whuber It looks like response surfaces are what I was looking for.  Do I simply do a high order polynomial fit to the data, then? Would the result be accurate for values between the data points? (I've noticed that with some data, a high order polynomial fit behaves unusually between data points, often shooting up to very high or low values.)

Comment: @Draksis, high order polynomials are not a very good idea when there are errors in data, like in your case. It's better to go for lower order polynomials like cubic splines, but with smoothing component in them (smoothing splines)

Comment: @Aksakal I did a bit of research, and I'm thinking that your answer is right - interpolation works well (better than response surfaces). I'll try to interpolate on the data and see how it goes.

Comment: +1 in light of the clarifications by the O.P. concerning the intent of the question.